Unity make gameobject completely unlit / Change shader of material (UnityGLTF)
Im making a FNAF fan game. The enviroment is therefore pretty dark. However, I want the animatronics(enemies) to be completely visible (Just like in the scene view or in blender). Is there a way to make a gameobject completely unlit in Unity?
Im using Models from the internet which are imported with UnityGLTF. I also tried changing the shader of the materials to the UnityGLTF/Unlit shader but that doesn't look right.
Material with "normal" shader
Material with unlit shader
Why does it look off? Can I change it to look like the normal shader?
I hope somebody knows a solution. Thank you.

Why does it look off .. because Unlit literally means out of the lighting cycle ... or the other way round: no shadows whatsoever ...

Instead you could just assign a certain layer to your enemies and then setup some light that only affects that specific layer .. e.g. URP / HDRP or simply directly through the Light.cullingMask
